# rails gem will_paginate on top of custom method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, will-paginate

In my controller, my filter_with_params() method is causing a syntax error in postgres when I try and stack will_paginate on top of it.

In my controller I call:

```
@styles = Style.filter_with_params(params).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
```

Model method:

```
class Style < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.filter_with_params(params)
    scoped = where("styles.item != ''")
    if params[:t]
      scoped = scoped.joins(:tags)
      scoped = scoped.select("distinct styles.*, count(*) AS count")
      scoped = scoped.where(tags: { name: params[:t] })
      scoped = scoped.group('styles.id')
      scoped = scoped.having("count(*) = #{params[:t].size}")
    end
    scoped
end
```

basically my filter method is looking for tags, and then i need to paginate on top of those results. Anyone with similar experience?

I'm using Rails 3 on this app

here is the postgres error

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "distinct" LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, distinct styles.*, count(*) AS...
                                  ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, distinct styles.*, count(*) AS count, styles.id AS styles_id FROM "styles" INNER JOIN "tagizations" ON "tagizations"."style_id" = "styles"."id" INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "tagizations"."tag_id" WHERE "tags"."name" IN ('engagement') AND (styles.polenza_item != '') GROUP BY styles.id HAVING count(*) = 1
```

Comment: You have SQL error in your query inside of `Style.filter_with_params` method.

Comment: Why are you making scoped equal a different scope in each line? Wouldn't you want to concatenate onto the scoped variable or am I missing something here?

Comment: @MarekLipka The filter_with_params method does not error until i append the paginate method

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL has a problem. You need to say distinct clause before the count ('count(*) as count_all'). That is, once you remove the first call to the count function, it should work.

```
SELECT distinct styles.*, count(*) AS count, styles.id AS styles_id FROM "styles" INNER JOIN "tagizations" ON "tagizations"."style_id" = "styles"."id" ...
```

You can test your query in your rails console:

```
>> sql = "SELECT distinct styles.*, count(*) AS count, styles.id AS styles_id..."
>> a = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
>> a[0]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all is coming from the paginate() method. My query works fine until i stack on the paginate method. Style.filter_with_params(:t => ["tagname"]) works fine. How would i reorder this or get paginate to work on top of my method?

Comment: it actually looks like only once i put the <%= will_paginate @styles %> into the page for the pagination controls is where the query breaks. Looks like the total record count is what breaks it